# How to send app requests using gigya

Tags: social-networking, gigya

I am planning to use GIGYA for my application. How would I send requests (like a post on the wall or notification)for my application to the user. So that I can actively engage user.

Answer (score 1):

you can't just post on one of your users wall with Gigya products
but you can make your site more social and give your users the ability to share things on your site with their friends with actions like posting on there wall

its very easy to do and implement just use the share plugin:

http://developers.gigya.com/010_Developer_Guide/18_Plugins/032_Share

or the share bar plugin:

http://developers.gigya.com/010_Developer_Guide/18_Plugins/015_Share_Bar